# How to solve this mathematical analysis limit problem?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

The following question is the third problem of the analysis section in the 2023 Mathematics Department Transfer Exam for Peking University.

“
Calculate the limit of sequence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\dfrac{k}{n^2}\right)^{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}$$
”

My idea is to transform the limit into some kind of Riemann integral, but I don't know how to do it.

Or there may be other methods, such as the Sandwich theorem, etc.

Comment: Consider that for every integer $k$, the limit is 0.

Comment: Apply the sandwich theorem using $1\le 1+{2k\over n^2}\le 1+{2\over n}.$ Pull out ${1\over n}$ .

Comment: @Tavasanis In $\sum_{k=1}^n {1\over n}$ the limit of each term is $0.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc. The limit of each term of the sum, as is, is 0. Then...

Comment: @Tavasanis ... there is no conclusion about the limit of the sum, as the number of terms depends on $n.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc. There may be no conclusion, but try prove that by induction on $k$, or even compute the first terms of the sum.

Comment: Using *Mathematica* with $n=100000$ results in a value of 1.4998218161335081308074447177220285829179521026841.  So I suspect that the limit is 3/2.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_n$ denote $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{k}{n^2}\right)^{1+\frac{2k}{n^2}}$

Since we know $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2}<1$, Then:

$a_n \leq$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})^1$

$a_n \leq n\frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2}$

$a_n \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$\limsup a_n \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{n^2}{2} = 3/2$

But then we also have:

$a_n \geq$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})^{1+2n/n^2}$

$a_n \geq$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})^{1+2/n}$

$a_n \geq$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})^{2/n}$

$a_n \geq$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})(\frac{1}{n})^{2/n}$

$a_n \geq (\frac{1}{n})^{2/n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{n^2})$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}^{\frac{2}{n}}=1$

Then we can basically argue that $\liminf a_n \geq 3/2$ as well.

Then we can conclude that $lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 3/2$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand how to do it now. It turns out that we really have to use the Sandwich theorem, and my thoughts about Riemann integration were more complicated than necessary.

Comment: np. glad I could help!